# ¿Qué hacen cada uno de estos comandos de este makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, make

Estoy intentando hacer un *makefile* en el terminal de *Cygwin* de un código en *C*, compilando en *GCC*. Estos comandos crean los archivos objeto solamente si ha habido alguna modificación con respecto a los ya existentes.

Este archivo de make funciona, pero, ¿Qué hace cada línea a partir de la 10? Me gustaría saber la utilidad de cada una de ellas:

```
CC=gcc -Wall
#LIBS = -lm
HEADER_FILES_DIR = .
INCLUDES = -I $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)
OUTPUT = ejecutable

SRCS = main.c potencia.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

#Here comes the problems
$(OUTPUT) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(OUTPUT) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los `makefile` existe el término `target`, que es el archivo al que se quiere llegar, en este caso el ejecutable del programa.

Entonces la estructura es:

1. `target`: Dependencias.
2. Comandos para llegar al objetivo.

También cabe recordar que al fin de cuentas el archivo **make** es un script basado en *Bash* por lo que cada vez que veas `$(x)` hace referencia a la variable `x`.

En la linea...

```
$(OUTPUT) : $(OBJS)
```

... lo que quiere decir es:

```
ejecutable: $(SRCS:.c=.o)
```

... o en otras palabras, para poder crear el ejecutable se necesitan todos los **.c** y **.o** de la carpeta:

```
%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Para crear todos los objetos de la carpeta se necesita correr el comando `$(CC)` el cual es tu compilador con las banderas `-c -o`. `$@` hace referencia al target y `$<` hace referencia a la primera referencia, por lo que es lo mismo si pusieras:

```
gcc -c -o NOMBRE_DEL_OBJETO NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO_.C -Wall
```